# Construct an approximate 0.95 confidence interval for alpha (Pareto distribution)

Tags: confidence-interval

[image]

I tried doing it by using the hint from the final answer but my answer is not the same. I also tried to do it using the mean and variance of Pareto distribution but I also did not get the right answer.

Here is my answer:

[image]

Can someone point out what I did wrong cause I tried many different ways and still could not get the right answer?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'd guess your estimate of $\alpha$ is wrong.

Comment: Any idea on how to get the right estimate of alpha? Cause I don't know what else to do